# How to denormalize a n_n relation in sql with view

Tags: mysql, join, multi-select

I have 2 tables

```
account
id | desc

Prices
id | desc
```

`Table account` stores users info while `table prices` stores several prices depending type of service.
Now, I need to assign prices that apply to each account.
I would like to display a result containg prices and an extra column that tells (`in form of a list`) the accounts that apply that service...

I was thinking on

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `id_account`            smallint(2) unsigned PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user`              VARCHAR(55) ,
    `pass`                  VARCHAR(55) ,
    `descr`           VARCHAR(250)      
); 
INSERT INTO account VALUES 
  (1,'67395'    ,  'pass1','DrHeL'),
  (2,'12316'    ,  'pass2','DeHrL'),
  (3,'92316'    ,  'pass3','EfL');

 CREATE TABLE `prices`(
 `id_price` smallint(2) unsigned PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `service`          VARCHAR(40), 
 `cost_1_1Kg`       double ,
 `cost_4_1Kg`       double ,
 `cost_8_1Kg`       double 
 );
INSERT INTO prices VALUES 
  (1,'laundry',  1.50, 2.00,5.00),
  (2,'walk.'  ,  2.50, 3.00,4.00);

CREATE TABLE `account_prices` (
  `id_account` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_price`  smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `descr` VARCHAR(250)
) ;  

INSERT INTO account_prices VALUES 
(1,1,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2'),
(2,1,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2'),
(3,1,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2'),
(1,2,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2'),
(2,2,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2'),
(3,2,'apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2');
```

This gives me

```
ID_ACCOUNT  ID_PRICE    DESCR   USER    PASS    SERVICE COST_1_1KG  COST_4_1KG  COST_8_1KG
1           1           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   67395   pass1   laundry 1.5 2   5
2           1           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   12316   pass2   laundry 1.5 2   5
3           1           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   92316   pass3   laundry 1.5 2   5
1           2           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   67395   pass1   walk.   2.5 3   4
2           2           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   12316   pass2   walk.   2.5 3   4
3           2           apply SERVICE WITH ID 1 AND SERVICE WITH ID 2   92316   pass3   walk.   2.5 3   4
```

However I would like somethink like:

```
ID_PRICE    SERVICE     COST_1_1KG  COST_4_1KG  COST_8_1KG descr
1           laundry     1.5         2           5          acount 1, account 2, account 3
2           walk.       2.5         3           4          acount 1, account 2, account 3
```

How to do It?

Please take a look at the corresponding fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16f05/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired output with this query:

```sql
select ap.id_price
     , p.service
     , p.cost_1_1Kg
     , p.cost_4_1Kg
     , cost_8_1Kg
     , group_concat(
         concat('account ', ap.id_account)
         order by ap.id_account
         separator ', '
     ) as descr
from account_prices ap
     inner join prices p using (id_price)
group by ap.id_price
```

Result:

```
| ID_PRICE | SERVICE | COST_1_1KG | COST_4_1KG | COST_8_1KG |                           DESCR |
|----------|---------|------------|------------|------------|---------------------------------|
|        1 | laundry |        1.5 |          2 |          5 | account 1, account 2, account 3 |
|        2 |   walk. |        2.5 |          3 |          4 | account 1, account 2, account 3 |
```

[Check updated SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16f05/16)

---

How this works:

1. You only need to join `account_prices` with `prices` to get all the data you need.
2. To get the `account x` stuff, concatenate `"account "` with the value of `id_account` using the `concat()` function
3. Finally, to get a concatenated group of values, use the `group_concat()` function. It works like any other aggregate function, but instead of performing an operation (like `sum()` or `count()`), it concatenates the values of the column (or expression). You can define the order you want for the output and a custom separator (the default separator is `,`.

Hope this helps you.